# Python: Compare 2 text files for string and then print context

Tags: python, string, text, find

I have 2 text files:

1) cities.txt

```
San Francisco
Los Angeles
Seattle
Dallas
```

2) master.txt

```
Atlanta is chill and laid-back.
I love Los Angeles.
Coming to Dallas was the right choice.
New York is so busy!
San Francisco is fun.
Moving to Boston soon!
Go to Seattle in the summer.
```

Trying to get output.txt

```
<main><beg>I love</beg><key>Los Angeles</key><end></end></main>
<main><beg>Coming to</beg><key>Dallas</key><end>was the right choice</end></main>
<main><beg></beg><key>San Francisco</key><end>is fun</end></main>
<main><beg>Go to</beg><key>Seattle</key><end>in the summer</end></main>
```

Each entity in cities.txt is the < key>. The master.txt file is much longer, and all lines without the particular city should just be ignored. They're not in order. The output prints out the cities in < key> and < beg> & < end> context (if any).

This is what I have:

```
with open(master.txt) as f:
    master = f.read()
working = []
with open(cities.txt) as f:
    for i in (word.strip() for word in f):
        if i in master:
            print "<key>", i, "</key>"
```

I know how to check two text files (find 'city' in 'master')... but stuck at the part how I can print the  and  context in master.txt once I find the city!

Answer (score 1):

Following should help you with what you want. This works with both Python2 as well as Python3.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

def parse(line, city):
    start = line.find(city)
    end = start + len(city)
    # Following is a simple implementation. I haven't parsed for spaces
    # and punctuations around tags.
    return '<main><beg>' + line[:start] + '</beg><key>' + city + '</key><end>' \
           + line[end:] + '</end></main>'

master = [line.strip() for line in open(os.getcwd() + '/master.txt', 'r')]
cities = [line.strip() for line in open(os.getcwd() + '/cities.txt', 'r')]
data = []

for line in master:
    for city in cities:
        if city in line:
            data.append(parse(line, city))

# Following would overwrite output.txt file in the current working directory
with open(os.getcwd() + '/output.txt', 'w') as foo:
    for output in data:
        foo.write(output + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work, testes with python 2.6:

```
cities_dict = {}
with open('master.txt', 'r') as master_in:
    with open('cities.txt') as city_in:
        for city in city_in:
            cities_dict[city.strip()] = '</beg><key>'+city.strip()+'</key><end>'

    for line in master_in:
        for key,val in cities_dict.iteritems():
            if key in line:
                line_out= '<main><beg>'+line.replace(key,val).replace('!','.').replace('.','').strip('\n')+'</end></main>'
                print line_out
```

Outputs:

```
<main><beg>I love </beg><key>Los Angeles</key><end></end></main>
<main><beg>Coming to </beg><key>Dallas</key><end> was the right choice</end></main>
<main><beg></beg><key>San Francisco</key><end> is fun</end></main>
<main><beg>Go to </beg><key>Seattle</key><end> in the summer</end></main>
```